# Implement callbacks for game state methods

Tags: design-patterns, unity-game-engine, libgdx, game-engine, implementation

In my game engine I want to have start() and update() callback methods much like in Unity3D. They will form 'GameListener' interface, which the user should implement to get to them. How do I implement these callbacks without adding any listeners?
For example, in libGDX, you have to implement ApplicationListener interface to get access to render() and start() methods without adding any listeners.

Answer (score 0):

```
//In class SomeTypeOfSender:  
public delegate void SomeHandler(SomeTypeOfSender A, EventArgs e); //whatever 
public event SomeHandler MyHandler;
```

To consume it like libGDX:

```
public class Listener
{
        public void Subscribe(SomeTypeOfSender  A)
        {
            A.MyHandler += new SomeTypeOfSender.SomeHandler (DoSth);
        }
        private void DoSth(SomeTypeOfSender s, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("HEARD IT");
        }
}
```